# Need to run a macro based on values in a column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

More specifically, what I need is to look up all the unique values in a column (these values are number representations of the months of the year) and use the value(s) returned to create a pop up box allowing the user to choose which macro to run. As an example, I import report data into a worksheet that contains 100 records. In column B we will see 11's and 12's representing November and December. What I am looking to do is capture those two numbers and use that to allow the user to run the code for November OR December. I have added code that I use for November as an example.

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1511_November()
'
'

' This line renames the worksheet to "Extract"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extract"

' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Select
    Range("P1").Activate
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select

' This unhides any hidden rows
Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("A2").Select

' Want to alter the code below to perform a query in column B to determine
' which months are listed from the import, then use the results in a dialog box to
' allow the user to choose which month to view

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "11" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next LR

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what you have tried to accomplish your goal? You won't find many who will **write your code for you**. Please post your efforts to create your pop-up. That said, you may want to consider just filling a range of cells on sheet with the months and then having the user double-click on the month they want and using the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` Event to fire the code.

Comment: Hi Scott. I am not looking for anyone to write the code for me. But a tip or suggestion as to what direction would work best. I am still learning VBA and do need a little direction. I like your suggestion for the BeforeDoubleClick event as an option. I have not attempted to tackle this part yet as I am not sure how to get this part to work, so I cannot provide information about what has worked or failed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a quicker way to achieve the true goal for this issue. Changed the order of the sort and hide sections. This now produces the desired results.

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1511_November()
'
'

' This line renames the worksheet to "Extract"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extract"

' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Select
    Range("P1").Activate
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select

' This unhides any hidden rows
Cells.Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("A2").Select

' Want to alter the code below to perform a query in column B to determine
' which months are listed from the import, then use the results in a dialog box to
' allow the user to choose which month to view

Dim LR As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
    .Apply
End With

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "11" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next LR

Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```